# Understanding the effect of num_words of Tokenizer in Keras

Tags: keras, tokenization

Consider the following code:

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = 5000)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(texts)
print('Found %d unique words.' % len(tokenizer.word_index))
```

When I run this, it prints:

```
Found 88582 unique words.
```

My question is, isn't `num_words` the parameter that controls the number of words in the mapping dictionary known as `tokenizer.word_index`? Then why it still holds `88582` words when I explicitly asked it to keep only `5000` words?

Comment: The library is (probably) printing total unique words found, but it would use only the top 5000 by frequency. The documentation is little unclear.

Comment: That's my own belief too.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the way things are documented. Check this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202519/keras-tokenizer-num-words-doesnt-seem-to-work